# Having trouble finding my core-data file on my macbook

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm running my app using Xcode 12.4 and I'm using persisting my data using Core Data.
When I try to fetch the data and print it inside of a list, it prints the data correctly, but I'm having trouble finding the actual DB file on my mac.

Normally I would run `print("Documents Directory: ", FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last ?? "Not Found!")`and that would lead me to the correct file, but when I go to the destination now, the documents folder is empty.

Any ideas how I can retrieve the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `NSPersistentContainer`, try asking the container for the path it's using. You can do this any time after calling `loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)`:

```
print("Path to store file: \(container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first?.url?.path ?? "not found")")
```

Or you can put this in the completion closure you pass to `loadPersistentStores(completionHandler:)`:

```
print("Loaded persistent store at \(storeDescription.url!.path)")
```

Keep in mind that the path will change every time you run the app, so be sure you have the current path. There are a couple of UUIDs in the path-- one of them doesn't change unless you delete the app, but the other changes all the time. For example once it might be this (wrapped here for readability)

```
/Users/[you]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
    445F0055-2A61-478A-9BA9-7F44CE038242/data/Containers/Data/Application/
    4B21151B-4148-470B-88AC-F323CB88434D/Library/
    Application Support/[AppName].sqlite
```

Then the next time it's this

```
/Users/[you]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
    445F0055-2A61-478A-9BA9-7F44CE038242/data/Containers/Data/Application/
    E8889B57-41CB-4F14-AAB2-A02142DC47FF/Library/
    Application Support/[AppName].sqlite
```

Which is kind of a pain, but you do need to check it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below to copy the location of core data database to the clipboard. If you are coding for IOS14 then you can comment out the appDelegate line and also swap the dbName line for the one commented.

```
func printCoreDataPath(){
  let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // remove if IOS14
  let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationSupportDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
  let dbName = appDelegate.persistentContainer.name
 // let dbName = PersistenceController.shared.container.name
  let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
  pasteboard.string = (path[0] + "/\(dbName).sqlite")
 print (path[0] + "/\(dbName).sqlite")
```

}

Comment: I call it like this as I am only interested in copying the path when using the simulator not on actual device:  #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
   printCoreDataPath()
   #endif